# Google Map radius to zoom level

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have a map with a custom UIView on top of it. I'm calculating the radius of the circle of according to the zoom level.

```
func getCenterCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    let centerPoint = self.mapView.center
    let centerCoordinate = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: centerPoint)
    return centerCoordinate
}

func getTopCenterCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    // to get coordinate from CGPoint of your map
    let topCenterCoor = self.mapView.convert(CGPoint(x:self.circleView.frame.size.width / 2.0, y:0), from: self.circleView)
    let point = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: topCenterCoor)
    return point
}

func getRadius() -> CLLocationDistance {

    let centerCoordinate = getCenterCoordinate()
    // init center location from center coordinate
    let centerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: centerCoordinate.longitude)
    let topCenterCoordinate = self.getTopCenterCoordinate()
    let topCenterLocation = CLLocation(latitude: topCenterCoordinate.latitude, longitude: topCenterCoordinate.longitude)

    let radius = CLLocationDistance(centerLocation.distance(from: topCenterLocation)) / 1000
    print(radius)
    return round(radius)
}
```

Now, I want to zoom the map according to a given radius? How could I do that ?

[image: Image1]

Comment: Your map is rectangle, so how would you want to map the circle to a rectangle? Once you decide that, you just have to call `mapView.setRegion()`.

Comment: Please Check my Answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any coordinate on the perimeter of the circle, and set the map's zoom or camera's zoom to the bounds of that coordinate, adding some padding ofcourse. Now for this logic, if your map is user enabled to be zoomed, you again have to recalculate everytime your map's camera is moveid or recentered.

You can use this method to do so : `mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 50.0))`

Here bounds is a `GMSCoordinateBounds` object.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But that is not really what I'm looking for.  For example I have at zoom level 4 a radius of 923 thank to those functions that I post above. What I want to to do is to find the zoom level I need to have  a radius of 10 for example.

Comment: This answer would automatically fit your zoom according to your radius, you dont have to explicitly give a zoom level