# GMSMapView: center map with radios

Tags: swift, gmsmapview

How do I position a camera of a GMSMapView, so it will be positioned in a predefined center and be zoomed out to show a radius?

```
let mapView: GMSMapView
let centerLocation: CLLocation
let radius: CLLocationDistance

mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(?)
```

[image]

Comment: Please find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733492/google-map-radius-to-zoom-level)